# Remove Redundant Premium Page Blob - LRS Snapshots

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I created a Azure VM with premium disks within a resource group. Later I deleted complete resource group. But I am  still getting bills with product name "Premium Page Blob - LRS Snapshots". I believe these are snapshots created for premium disks. Do I need to get these snapshots manually deleted to avoid charge on my billing? How to get these snapshot deleted?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to delete a blob which has snapshots in my container via Azure Storage Explorer, I got the error information as below.

[image]

[image]

These above said,

1. "Deleted blobs will be retained for 7 days", it may be protected by tool to avoid accidentally delete.
2. "This operation is not permitted because the blob has snapshots.", it means a blob can not be directly deleted if it has snapshots.

So first you should check the container for premium disks to confirm whether they are exist, then you can manually delete them thoroughly in Azure portal.

The steps to delete a blob is as below.

1. In Azure portal, to find your storage account and move into, then click the following buttons: `Blobs` -> `the container which has premium disks`.
2. Select these blobs of premium disks and right click to `delete`, then to enable the option `Also delete blob snapshots` and click `OK` to wait for the process done.

   [image]